# Split post like book to multiple pages in Hugo

Tags: post, hugo

I want to split post on hugo SSG is there a solution to divide the article like a book which contains many pages in several with pagination

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use a seperator or count words or characters to split the page. You can put each 'page' in its own div and then you can implement the paging as a javascript function that shows and hides divs. However... this is not really Hugo specific, more of a templating and front-end trick.

If the question is: can HUGO split an article into pages with pagination, I would say: No. One article is one page in Hugo.